# Java Unparseable Date Exception

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am trying to replace the hyphens with a forward slash, but it results to an `unparseable date exception`

```
    String test = "2014-04-01 05:00:00";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(test);
    System.out.println(date);
```

I have the necessary values for it to be converted, can someone tell me why it returns an error? Plus I wanted to append an `am/pm marker` at the end of the format, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse `String` to `Date` first in correct format as input `String`

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

then you can use format() to print it in other format

```
yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss
```

and don't expect `toString()` method of `Date` class return formatted value, it is fixed implementation

Answer (score 4):

From [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> ```
> Letter   Date or Time Component <br />
>   y      Year <br />
>   Y      Week year
>   H      Hour in day (0-23)
>   h      Hour in am/pm (1-12)
> ```

So, use `yyyy` for year and `HH` for hours in the day. Also, you're separating the fields by `-`, not by `/`:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(test);
```

After doing this, as @JigarJoshi suspects, you can format your `Date` to look with another format:

```
String dateInDesiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
```

Or written as a complete block of code:

```
DateFormat parse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

String test = "2014-04-01 05:00:00";
Date date = parse.parse(test);
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Produces the following output:

```
2014/04/01 05:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Add ` a` to the end of your parse format string to start parsing `AM/PM`

Comment: @JasonSperske it is not necessary from this code snippet.

Comment: I think OP wants to format date to `/` from `-` so he first need to parse and then format

Comment: Ahh I see they wanted to add it to the output

Comment: @JigarJoshi then OP would need to use two `SimpleDateFormat` instances.

Comment: @JasonSperske now you had reason by adding `a`. Thanks for edition

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between YYYY and yyyy. But I think @JigarJoshi got it first :)

Comment: @JerYango don't worry. We're here to help, so accept his answer if you like.

Comment: :) I was just explaining ante meridiem and post meridiem to my 7 year old daughter last night

Answer (score 1):

```
String test = "2014-04-01 05:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date oldDate = formatter.parse(test);
formatter.applyPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a");
Date newDate = formatter.parse(formatter.format(oldDate));
System.out.println(formatter.format(newDate));
```