# java.text.parseException: unparseable date 1994-09-09

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, prepared-statement

I am trying to send a date value from my java program into an oracle sql database. But I keep getting the error: java.text.parseexception: unparseable date.

I set the date format as:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        java.sql.Date date = (java.sql.Date)df.parse(dob_text.getText());
```

I have set my database with the same date format.
And try to send the date through a prepared statement like so:

```
ps.setDate(3, date);
```

I am entering a date 1994-09-09. That's the correct date format for the one I declared right? Is there something wrong with my java formation code? Has anyone else had this problem? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your format uses front slashes (`/`), but your date has dashes (`-`).

Comment: Are you getting a classcastexception?

Comment: The first element of the Question is also a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23569950/642706) and many [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unparseable+java). Please search StackOverflow.com before posting.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.sql.Date`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I corrected 2 errors :

- First of all, the format should have been `yyyy-MM-dd` since that's the format of your input.
- Then, you can not implicitely cast `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`, you need to use the `java.sql.Date` constructor and `java.util.Date#getTime()`. [**See here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

---

### Solution

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
java.sql.Date SQLDate = new java.sql.Date(df.parse(dob_text.getText()).getTime());
```

Comment: You sir.. are a genius! Thank you!

Comment: @Cillin Which I was:p You're welcome :)

Comment: and I don't feel this question should be marked down. It wasn't really an obvious answer for a noob..

Comment: @Cillin Indeed it was not, but that happens, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Cillín No, not an obvious answer. But both elements of the question have been covered *many* times already on StackOverflow.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.sql.Date`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your first try probably threw the exception you mentioned because of the wrong format as Josh pointed out. After correcting this the next problem occurs: 
A java.sql.Date is NOT a java.util.Date. So you cannot just typecast the outcome of the df.parse, which is a java.util.Date.
And third: If you provide the pattern to the SimpleDateFormat you can omit the locale.
Following code runs without errors:

```
    String input = "1994-09-09";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = df.parse(input);
    System.out.println( date);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date( date.getTime() );
    System.out.println( sqlDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your format to yyyy-MM-dd.

I just wrote this program and it works fine. Make sure you aren't getting some other error now.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateFormatDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(df.parse("1994-09-09"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't do the trick..

Comment: Good deal. Please accept the answer. Just hitting the up arrow doesn't accept it as being the correct answer.

Comment: I can't accept it if it didn't work. I got the error java.lang.classcastexception java.util.date cannot be cast to java.sql.date

Comment: @JoshChappelle It did NOT do the trick :)

Comment: @Cillín Then use `new java.sql.Date(df.parse(...).getTime());`

Comment: Oh thought you said did the trick. Sorry. Are you sure the date you are passing to the formatter is the String you think it is? Add System.out.println(dob_text.getText()) before your df.parse to see what the string is

Comment: Also, try removing Locale.ENGLISH